# Data is not coming from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, connection

It is showing that connection has been created. But I don't know what is the problem in query. After that query I tried to echo something and it is visible there in browser.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost:8888";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "employees";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}

$res = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from dept_manager");
echo"dept_manager";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_no'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dept_no']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['from_date'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['to_date'] ?></td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Add a catch for errors: `if($res = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from dept_manager")){ } else { echo mysqli_error($conn); }`

Comment: It is not showing any type of error. But the only thing is that it is not working on browser. As I am using same query in directly in DB it is giving data.

Comment: echo mysqli_num_rows($res); //Check it what its returning. Are you sure you are selecting the right database?

Comment: Is your database connected  successfully or not?

Comment: Database is successfully connected.

Comment: check the php.ini and make sure php error reporting is turned on and it's set to return all types of errors.

Comment: Inplace of 'if ($conn->connect_error)' i tried 'if (mysqli_connect_errno())' now it is working fine. Thanks all of you for giving me these valuable solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have mentioned servername:localhost:8888 just check once remove
>   8888 and try.

I have tried with your code in my local system,same code working fine.

Just i have entered my database name and table name,it's working fine.

So you just follow my example and test once.

**COde:-**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydashboard";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else{
echo "Connected successfully";
}

$res = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from content_values");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:-**

```
Connected successfully

Name:
Test QA AndroidSD
image sampl
GMAIL
test PDF
Nat Geo Video
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "select * from dept_manager";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      // your code here
```

}

Try with this..

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the place of while loop:

```
<?php
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from dept_manager");
    echo"dept_manager";
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row['emp_no'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dept_no'] . "</td><td>" . $row['from_date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['to_date'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```